# Drag and drop text from TRichEdit to ListBox without affecting text selection

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, richedit

I have a richedit(richedit1) and a listbox(listbox1),
I want to drag the richedit1.text  without affecting its text selection. here some code:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
     Accept := (Source is TRichEdit) ;
end;     

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    if Source is TRichEdit then ListBox1.Items.Add(RichEdit1.SelText);
end;
```

When i set RichEdit1.DragMode to dmAutomatic, draging works fine, but i can not select text in richedit by mouse.
I know one solution is Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.RichEdit1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Sender is TCustomRichEdit) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then
       TCustomRichEdit(Sender).BeginDrag(False);
end;
```

But i don't want to drag by holding ctrl key;
Do you have any better idea?

Comment: - *"..draging works fine, but i can not select text in richedit by mouse.."* - I wonder why. I dropped a TRichEdit on a brand new VCL Forms Application, and selecting by mouse and then automatic dragging works fine. I tested this on D7, D2007 and XE2.

Comment: Sertac,  I also tested your example in Delphi XE5, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the `OnMouseDown` event, you can detect if the mouse is being clicked inside of an existing selection that is 1+ characters in size, and if so then start dragging. Look at the `EM_CHARFROMPOS` and `EM_GETSEL` messages for that.